# Slate.js - How to get Absolute Text Selection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, slatejs, slate

I'm trying to implement a collaborative text editor using **Slate.js**, with React and Typescript. For applying text styling and broadcasting to other clients, I need the **exact selection of the text** that the user wants to change style, in the following format:

```js
type Cursor = {
  line: number;
  column: number;
};

type Selection = {
  start: Cursor;
  end: Cursor;
};
```

With this approach, the current styles of the text affect the output, because it is dependent on the tree structure of the slate document.
What I would like to **get is the current selection no matter the document structure**, but the returning columns are incorrect, in the following way:

```js
function getSelection(editor: Editor): Selection {
  const { selection } = editor;
  if (!selection) {
    return {
      start: { line: 0, column: 0 },
      end: { line: 0, column: 0 },
    };
  }
  const [start, end] = Range.edges(selection);
  return {
    start: pointToCursor(start),
    end: pointToCursor(end),
  };
}

function pointToCursor(point: Point): Cursor {
  return {
    line: point.path[0],
    column: point.offset, // wrong
  };
}
```

For example, with the text `abcdef`, if I select `def` it returns the columns as **[0, 3]**, instead of **[3, 6]**, but if `abc` is in a different style (in a another node of the document tree) it returns **[3, 6]**.

Thanks for the help in advance.